# git-receive-pack fails from Windows cmd ssh session

Tags: ssh, git, windows-10

I am trying to set up a shared git repo on my Synology NAS. I have checked many step by step articles but don't get why my regular git user cannot clone the repo from Windows cmd and Visual Studio.

After a long investigation, I have the feeling the root cause is **git-receive-pack** behaving differently for my git user from the Windows cmd and a putty session.

If I try from cmd:

`ssh user@host git-receive-pack /path/to/repo`

I only get:

`008d0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 capabilities^{}`

On the contrary, if I open a **putty** session to the NAS with the same user and run

`git-receive-pack /path/to/repo`

it returns more:

`008d0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 capabilities^{}report-status delete-refs side-band-64k quiet atomic ofs-delta agent=git/2.26.2 0000`

Anyone having an idea what makes this difference?

Windows 10, ssh version in cmd is:

`OpenSSH_7.6p1, LibreSSL 2.5.3`

openssh is configured for rsa key auth.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have found the issue. I have the **GIT_SSH** global environment variable set and pointing to **plink.exe**. After adding the ssh key to **pageant** it works.
It also works if **GIT_SSH** variable is unset, but I need that for other repos I already use.